# Click command doesn't work on Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to do a click  on this element:

```
<img src="img/error.gif">
```

This action make the `src=""` change.
I have tried click and clickAt but no one of those commands work.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: add your code please, and language used

Comment: `img` is not an actionable element. Post more of your HTML. Probably one of the parent elements are actionable.

Comment: It's possible that the javascript event that handles the click isn't being executed.  Are you sure that you're clicking the right img tag?